# using Image_tag, render an alternative if the load fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I am using active storage with rails 5.2.4, my attached file is named photo, I want to render "default.jpg" if the loading of the image failed (for example the image got delete from the storage), thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <%= image_tag'batman.png', alt: 'hello', :onerror => "this.src='hulk.png'"  %>
```

Comment: yes this is working, (but the images should be inside public folder and not the assets folder) thanks

Comment: also you can make it as default in the migration file ex:  ```add_column :movies, :image_file_name, :string, default: 'placeholder.png'```

Comment: The issue I am facing is that only in storage the file is deleted, the record still in the database so rails will try to find a file that does not exist and the asset load will fail. So default value in the database will not do the job.

Comment: you can do something like this :   ```<% if model.image.attached? %> <%= image_tag model.image %><% else %> <%= image_tag 'placeholder' %><%end%>```